# How to check what an exception is in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, exception

So basically I want to be able to somehow do a few if statements to check what exception is being thrown in order for me to `echo` out some appropriate error messages, e.g.

IF exception is a duplicate record exception in MySQL 
THEN `echo "User Already exists";`

So below I have caught the exception and it prints the default exception error message however this doesn't look good for the user so I want to check what the error is, then print out my own appropriate error message that users would be able to recognise... such as 'User Already Exists'.

```
try{
$query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('', 0, $safe_email, '$hashed_password')";

$result = $db->query($query);

echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'You have successfully registered.\n A confirmation email has been sent to you.\'); window.location = \'index.php\'; </script>';
}
 catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the user exists in a "non exceptional" way first, since it's impossible, or at least pretty tricky, to get relevant and consistent information out of the MySQL exception.

For example, if you suddenly decide to add an `id` field to your table and set it as a primary key, your algorithm would break. If you manage to parse the MySQL error by identifying the error number or something, you're also very tightly coupled to your database and it might be tricky to switch to MariaDB or Postgres or whatever...

Leave the exceptions for the truly exceptional cases, such as

- User A and B tries to sign up as "Adam" at roughly the same time
- Your server checks `UserModel->usernameExists("Adam")` of something like that, it returns `false` in both cases.
- Your registration controller continues the registration process for both users, user A gets registered but user B receives an exception, which is actually exceptional and due to this stupid race condition).

If user A registers two weeks before user B tries to register, however, `UserModel->usernameExists("Adam")` would just return `true` for user B, and you could show a nice error - or just show that the username is taken, in the registration form.